# JavaScript inner function prints previous value

Tags: javascript

Although code like this is probably not best practice, I ran into something strange while working the other day. Recreating it as a simple example, I expected the following code to alert 'dog' and then 'cat', but instead it alerted 'dog' twice. By my understanding of JavaScript closure, that seems like very odd behavior to me. Anyone have a good explanation for this?

```
var printMan = {
    printer: function(animal){
        this.innerPrinter =  this.innerPrinter || function(){
             alert(animal)   
        }
        this.innerPrinter(animal)
    }
}

printMan.printer('dog' )
printMan.printer('cat')
```

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xBvH/)

Edit -----
Thanks everyone for the great explanations. This is one of the reasons why I love this language - there's a great community here. I thought I knew a great deal about the language, but I was wrong about how this function would work. For anyone reading this, it's probably best to not do something like this example.

Comment: it's because it cached the result and now `this.innerPrinter` is pointing to the first ever result and it is not a function anymore.

Comment: Perhaps `cache` is technically not the correct word to describe it, but it does (at least loosely) describes the process...

Comment: That is a questionable "inner function" because it adds itself to `this` as a side-effect. That is, it only exists (on printMan) after `printMan.printer()` and is never used externally and captures the first (and then stale) variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you assign to `this.innerPrinter` does not have any arguments in its definition:

```
function(){
    alert(animal)   
}
```

So when you call it with `this.innerPrinter(animal)`, it ignores the argument and gets `animal` from the wider scope (which is `printer: function(animal){`).

The first time you call `printer`, the object does not have a `innerPrinter` value, so you assign a new function to it.

This function is declared within the scope of the *first* call to `printer`, so `animal` is `'dog'`. It alerts `'dog'`.

The second time you call the function, `this.innerPrinter` already has a value, so `this.innerPrinter || function(){` evaluates as the function from the *first* call. It therefore alerts `'dog'` because that is the value of `animal` for the first function generated from the function expression.

Comment: Great explanation. Recreating this, I made a mistake calling the inner print with an argument at all, but it would have been the same result. Truly appreciate the explanation. I thought I knew most about JavaScript but this was still a learning experience.

Answer (score 3):

It is in fact perfectly normal that you are getting two dogs. You forgot the parameter in the inner function. It should look like this:

```
var printMan = {
    printer: function(animal){
        this.innerPrinter =  this.innerPrinter || function(animal){
             alert(animal)   
        }
        this.innerPrinter(animal)
    }
}

printMan.printer('dog' )
printMan.printer('cat')
```

Let me try to explain. The first time you go trough the `printer` function, the `innerPrinter` gets constructed, and the variable is hard coded in there from it's parent scope. The second time you call the `printer`, the `innerPrinter` you made in the previous cycle is used, with your hard coded *dog* in there. By passing the parameter it is not hard coded and you will get the expected cat on the second run. Changing the variable names may make it a bit clearer:

```
  printer: function(animal){
        this.innerPrinter =  this.innerPrinter || function(innerAnimal){
             alert(innerAnimal)   
        }
        this.innerPrinter(animal)
    }
```

Hope this makes sense. Feel free to ask if you want me to explain further.

Comment: it might be a little clearer if the argument in `alert(animal)` were renamed to something else so there is no variable shadowing

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `animal` variable as a parameter to the `innerPrinter` to execute differently.  Like:

```
var printMan = {
    printer: function (animal) {
        this.innerPrinter = this.innerPrinter || function (animal) { 
            alert(animal);
        }
        this.innerPrinter(animal);
    }
}

printMan.printer('dog');
printMan.printer('cat');
```

Comment: Looks like @PeterVR beat me by a few seconds - it is exactly what he said ;)